# Expressing and defining logic

Tags: logic, chatbot, dsl

I am trying to express a certain logic for a GUI tool to make diagnoses easier.

At the starting Point always the same questions will be asked (Question A). Dependet on the answer to it the questions should get more specific and complex.

Possible Scenario: *Question A* -> YES -> *Question B* -> NO -> *Question E* -> NO -> *Question C* .....
[image: Graphical Desciption]

So the application kind of walks a path dependet on the answers. How can i define such a logic, best in a graphical way? Is it solveable with a domain specific language? I know some DSL-languages like ANTLR, but how can I export the logic and import it to GUI? I would like to write the GUI preferrably in C#, are there some constructs existing that would me help?

Anyone faced a similar issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

[Activity diagrams](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unified-modeling-language-uml-activity-diagrams/) are what you are looking for. Something like this:
[image: Activity Diagram with swim lanes]

Use swim lanes to denote different "actors" in the system. From what it looks like in the image you posted in the question, you may not need swim lanes. Your software career will benefit from knowing [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)/[SysML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Modeling_Language), both make use of activity diagrams.

Create the diagram, then write the code to match. Hyperlink the code to the diagram with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) comments, so then you can generate a nice html/pdf page to explain how the code works.